# Can I use 2 Solr cores for reindexing and searching simultaneously?

Tags: solr, lucene, plone

I am using the **Collective Solr 4.1.0** Search on our **Plone 4.2.6** system.

I am running a solr_core on my server that is currently being used by our Plone live system's search. Now I want to build a new index but **without shutting down the live system search** for 10 or more hours (time for reindexing). Doing that on the same core is only available on collective.solr 5.0 and higher versions. See [collective.solr changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.solr/5.0.3).

Is there way for me to build a new index on another core while still being able to use the search on the currently used core? I thought of it like this: live_system uses `core_1` for query and builds a new index on `core_2`. Once the index is built, switch both cores so that the live_system now uses `core_2` for its search.

I know there is a way to load an already built Solr index into a Solr core, but I can't figure out how do accomplish this switcheroo I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the Master- Slave architecture. That might can help here !!
Check the following link- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication